# Regression calculation of initial individual weight considering variations in weighing dates and missing data

Tags: regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I need to determine the initial individual weight of each animal as accurately as possible, taking into account the following challenges:

1. The animals may be weighed on different days.
2. There may be missing data for some animals.

To address these issues, I currently use the formula:

$$ \text{Initial Individual Weight} = \text{Initial Total Weight} \cdot\dfrac{\text{Final Individual Weight}}{\text{Final Total Weight}}  $$

However, this formula doesn't account for the weighing date variations and missing data. How can I adapt the calculation to overcome these challenges? Complexity is not a concern as the data is stored in a database, and I have the ability to create a script to perform this calculation.

**Example**:

- On January $1, 2023$, at $15:00:00$, I recorded the entry of $10$ sheep with a total weight of $100$ kilograms.
- Subsequently, I obtained the individual weights for each sheep on different dates. However, one of them was not weighed.

| Sheep | Date | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sheep1 | 2023-01-15 09:12:00 | 15kg |
| sheep2 | 2023-01-16 14:25:00 | 10kg |
| sheep3 | 2023-01-17 11:34:00 | 12kg |
| sheep4 | 2023-01-18 18:52:00 | 14kg |
| sheep5 | 2023-01-19 07:41:00 | 11kg |
| sheep6 | 2023-01-20 16:59:00 | 13kg |
| sheep7 | 2023-01-21 22:08:00 | 16kg |
| sheep8 | 2023-01-22 12:37:00 | 9kg |
| sheep9 | 2023-01-23 05:19:00 | 17kg |

Comment: May I ask where this question is from? Is this an exercise? Are you actually working with sheep or is this fictitious data? If it's the latter, what statistical methods have you learned, what do you know? Averages, variances, integrals, distributions, probability densities, hypothesis testing, etc.?

Comment: I would guess the weight of the final ($10$'th) sheep, by the average of the recorded weight amounts, which is
$$\frac{15+10+\dots+17}{9}=13\text{ kg}$$
So the total "new" weight of the sheep is $117+13=130$ kg. That means each sheep has grown by a factor of $1.3$ on average, so the initial sheep weights were (probably around) $1/1.3 \approx 0.76923$ (about $76.9%$) of their current weights.
However this also doesn't take into consideration that the "new" weight values were measured from the $15$'th to the $23$'rd, so there might be an even better method to correct for this time difference.

Comment: This is actually a requirement for a software that I'm building. I made the mistake of using fictional information. The actual data I'm working with involves cows, which enter weighing approximately 300-350 kilograms and increase by around 1.2kg every 24 hours, regardless of whether it's day 1 or day 180.

Comment: The proposed solution is good; however, it still doesn't account for the time difference between weighings. I was thinking of extrapolating all the weighings to either the first or the last day and calculating it that way. However, my limited mathematical knowledge prevents me from knowing if it's the best approach or not.